# Identification of a WW1 German shell casing?

Tags: identification, world-war-one, artillery, german, shell-casings

I have what I believe is a German WW1 shell casing.  It is marked RhMF (54?) MARZ 1918 Düsseldorf. Approximately 8 1/2” diameter, 9 1/8” tall, 12 1/2 pounds.

Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Adding a photo might make identification a bit easier.

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_cm_schwerer_LadungsWerfer_Ehrhardt

Comment: "RhMF" would be the manufacturer *Rheinmetall* (originally: *Rheinische Metallwaren- und Maschinenfabrik*) located in Düsseldorf.

Comment: The caliber of 8.5" as stated in the question equates to about 215 mm. The only land-based artillery I can think of that is close would be various models of 21cm Mörser, such as the [21cm  Mörser 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21_cm_M%C3%B6rser_16). Maybe it's from a shell for a naval gun (I do not known anything about those)?

Comment: I think the Mörser idea is a good one. Rheinmetall (RhMF) made a test canon, together with Krupp in 1906. However, the successful one of the two was Krupp, not RhMF, so I'm confused why they would have made ammunition for this one as late as March 1918 (especially since they stopped really using the normal Mörsers in Oktober 1918). Maybe the 54 number could help?